# How to grep json values with out sorting

Tags: json, shell, unix, grep

This is the part of json. I want to get the value for "state" when the name is "US". But if you see the json we have many occurrences where the name is  "US". But I need to get the first occurrence "US" in the entire json. Hence the out put will be

OUTPUT:
"FINISHED" (the first occurrence where "US" has occurred)

I used 
grep -A 5 "US" | cut -d ':' -f2 | sort -u`
But it does not turn out well.

grep : to find out US
-A 5: to print next 5 lines
-u: to remove duplicates

But I am not sure how to remove duplicated with out sorting
Any help?

```
{

    "starttime" : 1533557223447,
    "id" : "app-20180806120703-6027",
    "name" : "US",
    "cores" : 5,
    "user" : "spark",
    "memoryperslave" : 8192,
    "submitdate" : "Mon Aug 06 12:07:03 UTC 2018",
    "state" : "FINISHED",
    "duration" : 184631
  }, 
{

    "starttime" : 1533557411909,
    "id" : "app-20180806121011-6028",
    "name" : "US",
    "cores" : 5,
    "user" : "spark",
    "memoryperslave" : 8192,
    "submitdate" : "Mon Aug 06 12:10:11 UTC 2018",
    "state" : "FAILED",
    "duration" : 135928
  }, 
{

    "starttime" : 1533557551584,
    "id" : "app-20180806121231-6029",
    "name" : "US",
    "cores" : 5,
    "user" : "spark",
    "memoryperslave" : 8192,
    "submitdate" : "Mon Aug 06 12:12:31 UTC 2018",
    "state" : "KILLED",
    "duration" : 136974
  }, 
{

    "starttime" : 1533557692376,
    "id" : "app-20180806121452-6030",
    "name" : "CA - CONGO STREAM",
    "cores" : 5,
    "user" : "spark",
    "memoryperslave" : 8192,
    "submitdate" : "Mon Aug 06 12:14:52 UTC 2018",
    "state" : "FINISHED",
    "duration" : 187685
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq`, which is like sed and grep for JSON. In you example:

```
$>jq '[.[]| select( .name == "US")][0] | .state' sample.json
```

Feeding your json into `jq`, I select all the US objects, wrap that selection in an array and choose the first item, then print the state of that first item. Output is:

```
"FINISHED"
```

See Jq documentation for more details (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

If you're really stuck on using grep, then this will suffice:

```
grep -A 5 "US" | grep  "state.*:.*\"[A-Z]\+\"" | cut -d: -f2 | head -1
```

Comment: Bewilderingly, `grep -m1 -A5 "US"` only gets me a single line of output on MacOS High Sierra, whereas `grep -m5 -A5 "US"` gets me multiple matches, with context.  Maybe the latter still helps a little bit if your real-life output is much larger than the sample in the question.

Comment: @tripleee MacOS uses BSD grep, instead of gnu grep. In that version, -m immediately stops reading the file after the last match. To workaround this, use -B and search for 'state' (i.e. reverse the search); use --context; or install gnu grep with homebrew (it will install as 'ggrep').

Comment: Yeah, I thought I had an improvement but it didn't work on *BSD. I thought I'd still comment in case others might waste time on discovering the same thing.